# UINavigationController suggestion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have read that `UINavigationController` are best option when you want to jump from n number of screen to first screen. It takes following  code to do so:

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewController];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[array removeObjectAtIndex:1];
self.navigationController.ViewController=array;
[self.navigationController popViewController:YES];
```

by using this code I can go directly from fourth screen to first screen directly .
If I don't using navigation controller then also by making the object of firstSCreen in fourth screen I can achieve the same thing within couple of lines.Then why one should go for navigation controller? If answer is for memory optimization then we are autoreleasing the the object of firstViewController and now we are using auto referencing.

Comment: refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) link. Hope you will get answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first thing this is wrong approach to pop. true one is

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewController:YES];
```

and second thing is that if you are at 4 screen, then by poping to a specific viewcontroller will no pop all screens. here is memory issue.

another issue is that some times you don't want to lose parent screens data. if you use method of pop to specific viewcontroller, the data will be lost as the object having data is released. you made a new one.

point is that this depends on your conditions what is suit able in your scenario. but the normal and usual approach is that don't use specific popout techniqu as it may cause problems

Comment: but by using second case also we can move two the specific controller .

Comment: yes sure we can, but that depends on case, if you want to go to some new controller which is not already in navigation controller. if it is in navigationcontroller, then you are making another object as well there may be some other controolers too.

Comment: if you want to move back to a specific view controller, you can use also [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]];

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`[self.navigationController popToViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL)];`

You just need to pass ViewController's object on which you want to move directly... And between view controller's will pop-out automatically

Hope this helps you...

Answer (score 0):

agreed with 'The Saad'

one more thing is that if you have various screens with the data coming from server.
it will be quite difficult to render(user interection) screen second while loding data on first.

same with all other sibling views.